# How to fix PDF files corrupted when downloaded via PHP

Tags: php, pdf, download

## The problem

I just rebuilt our website, in which we allow users to download .pdf and .mp3 files. I'm using a PHP script to handle the download process. The problem is that, with .pdf files, most of the times the downloads succeed. But certain times, I don't know why, the downloaded file is corrupted. Or, actually, Adobe Reader says "There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired". If I open the same damaged file with another reader, it works fine.

## What I already did

What I did is I opened both a "good" file and a "damaged" file with Notepad++. I found that the problem is that the damaged file, instead of ending with %%EOF, there's more stuff after %%EOF. It looks like if the beginning of the PDF file has been copied to the end of the file. 
I also checked the file stored on the server, and it is good. 
So, at this point, I think there's something wrong with the php script that handles the download.

## Here's the code:

```
    <?php

    $file =$_GET['file']; 
    if(file_exists($file)) {

      $fileExtension = substr($file, -3);
      if($fileExtension === "pdf"){
        $filenameIndex = strpos($file, "pdf/") + 4;
        $filename = basename($file);

      }
      elseif ($fileExtension === "mp3") {
        $filenameIndex = strpos($file, "mp3/") + 4;
        $filename = basename($file);
      }

      header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
      header('Content-length: '. filesize($file));
      header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
      header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
      header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: chunked');
      readfile($file);
      print file_get_contents($file);
      exit;
    }
    ?>
```

I use the same script to download both .pdf and .mp3 files.

I'm NOT a php expert. And don't really understand how php handles downloads, so I would really appreciate if somebody could help me find the problem. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You are outputting the file content _twice_, by having `readfile($file);` followed by `print file_get_contents($file);` - remove the second of those lines.

Comment: And remove `header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: chunked');`, that makes no sense here, the script is not actually sending the content in chunks.

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you very much, that was the issue. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
readfile($file);
print file_get_contents($file);
```

The script is outputting the file content *twice* here, both of those two lines do basically the same thing. Remove the second one.

```
 header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: chunked');
```

That does not really make sense here, the script is not actually sending the content out in chunks. And when `Content-Transfer-Encoding` is specified, a `Content-Length` should not be specified at the same time. If it currently works this way, that is rather by accident, but it might trip up clients you have not tested. This header should also be removed.